# Ignore UnexpectedAlertPresentException from Chromedriver and Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chromdriver to request few URLs, some of them have many alerts in the HTML response (I am ignoring how many alerts: there are sometimes 3 alerts, sometimes 1, sometime no alerts).

I always ignore if I will receive an `alert()` in the HTML response (and how many alerts?). Is there a way to ignore ALL alerts ? Capabilities `unhandledPromptBehavior` and `UnexpectedAlertBehaviour` don't work, and `--disable-popup-blocking` also does not work

My current code is:

```
    def isAlertPresent(driver):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            return True
        except NoAlertPresentException as e:
            return False



    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    chrome_options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'dismiss')
    chrome_options.set_capability('UnexpectedAlertBehaviour', 'dismiss')
    chrome_options.add_argument("User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    if isAlertPresent(driver) is True:
        print("Alert? on {0}".format(url))
```

Is there a way to ignore any alerts ? I am getting exceptions like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: 请确保/plus/user_data.php文件存在!

Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : 请确保/plus/user_data.php文件存在!}
```

Or another solution would be to add a callback to the Alert, in order to always accept it.

Thank you !

Comment: --disable-notifications should be enough. Try only with this option without others - Does it work? Why do you try to use another options to handle it? I think they could intersect the behavior of disable-notifications option.

Comment: Hello gore, thank you for your answer, it does not work with --disable-notifications  only :(